# Example of a Tate Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1\right|}
\newcommand{\ab}{\left|-\right|}
\newcommand{\nrm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\newcommand{\nr}{\nrm{-}}
\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
Let $K$ be non-Archimedean valued and complete.
Define $\mathbb{T}_n(K)\colon =\{f=\sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n}f_\alpha X^\alpha\in K[X_1,\cdots,X_n]\mid f_\alpha\to 0,\left\|\alpha\right\|\to \infty\}$, $\left\|\alpha\right\|:=\max\{\left|\alpha_1\right|,\cdots,\left|\alpha_n\right|
 \}$.

This is a $K$-algebra.
Define $\left\|f\right\|:=\max\{\left|f_\alpha \right|,\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n
 \}$.
I want to show that this $K$-algebra is complete with respect to the above defined norm.
It is obvious, that because of It is obvious that because of $\abs{f_\a^{(i)}-f_\a^{(j)}}\leq \nrm{f^{(i)}-f^{(j)}}$ every Cauchy-sequence $(f^{i}=\sum_{\a\in\N^n}f_\a^{(i)}X^\a)_{i\in\N}$ in $\T_n$ gives rise to a Cauchy-sequence $(f_\a^{(i)})_{i\in\N}$ in $K$ and because $K$ is complete, it must converge to an element $f_\a\in K$.
So if we let $f:=\sum_\a f_\a X^\a$, then we need to prove $f^{(i)}\to f$ and $f\in \mathbb{T}_n(K)$.
I fail proving the second assertion:
It seems, that a straightforward argument is not possible:
The assertion should follow from:

$1.)$
$f_\a^{(i)}\to f_\a$ for all $\a$ :
Let $\a\in\N^n$ be arbitrary. Then for every $\eps>0$ there is $j_\a\in \N$ such that for all $i\geq j_\a$ we have $\abs{f_\a^{(i)}-f_\a}<\eps$.
and

$2.)$
$f_\a^{(i)}\to 0,\nrm{\a}\to \infty$, for all $i$:
Let $i$ be arbitrary.

Then for every $\eps>0$ there is a $k_i$ such that for all $\alpha\colon \nrm{\a}\geq k_i$ we have $\abs{f_\a^{(i)}}<\eps$.

Of course the idea is to combine these two inequalities to get $f_\a\to 0, \nrm{\a}\to \infty$, however $k$ depends on $i$ and $j$ depends on $\a$. If we assume, that $j$ would be independent of $\a$, a proof would be easy, but I don't see why this should be true.

I am pretty sure, that $j$ must be independent of $\a$, but I don't see the argument.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that properties 1 and 2 are enough to get what you want, however, you could still use that $(f^{(i)})$ is a Cauchy-sequence and then I think the following should work.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $(f^{(i)})_i$ is a Cauchy-sequence, there exists a $N > 0$ such that $$\|f^{(i)} - f^{(j)}\| < \varepsilon$$ for all $i,j \geq N$.

By property $2$ there exists a $k > 0$ such that $$ |f_\alpha^{(N)}| < \varepsilon $$ for all $\alpha$ with $\|\alpha\| \geq k$.

Now let $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ be such that $\|\alpha\| \geq k$ and choose some $i \geq N,j_\alpha$ with $j_\alpha$ as in property $1$.

We then have 
$$ |f_\alpha| \leq |f_\alpha - f_\alpha^{(i)}| + |f_\alpha^{(i)} - f_\alpha^{(N)}| + |f_\alpha^{(N)}| < 3 \varepsilon  $$

and this shows $f_\alpha \to 0$ for $\|\alpha\| \to \infty$.